Shopify run query on cart returns hasAnyTag false
I currently have a product with the tag = CL Og test
I have a metafield in my shop when queried it returns like this:
"node": {
"id": "gid://shopify/Metafield/32266534555929",
"key": "\"discountSpecs\"",
"value": "{\"selectedCollectionIds\":[\"gid://shopify/Collection/310827712556\"],\"tags\":[\"CL Og test\",\"VIP234234\"]}",
"namespace": "cldiscounts"
}

I then query my cart like so:
query RunInput($tags: [String!]) {
  cart {
    lines {
      id
      quantity
      merchandise {
        ... on ProductVariant {
          id
          product {
            handle
            hasAnyTag(tags: $tags)
          }
        }
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
}

hasAnyTags always returns false and I have no idea why I'm sure the product has the tag.
To call this tag in a function I have it set in shopify.extensions.toml to
  [extensions.input.variables]
  namespace = "cldiscounts"
  key = "discountSpecs"

if I manually set
hasAnyTag(tags: "CL Og test") then it returns true.
Any idea why it doesn't read the tag in the json object that is set?
